# jquery steps - content floating right

Tags: jquery, jquery-steps

I tried running the basic example in a clean page.  By default my content box sits off to the right rather than below the step buttons:

[image: screen shot]

Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="Scripts/jquery.steps.js"></script>
  <link href="Content/jquery.steps.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wizard">
    <h1>First Step</h1>
    <div>First Content</div>

   <h1>Second Step</h1>
   <div>Second Content</div>
  </div>

    <script>
      $("#wizard").steps();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

There is an overflow being set on the outer content div, but I'm hesitant to dig into this when I'm having problems with an extremely simple wizard.  I'm hoping there is a required container that was missed in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.  The code is applying a clearfix class but either the author intends you to supply your own or neglected to include it in the css.  I ended up taking it out of his demo "main.css" in github:

```
/*
 * Clearfix: contain floats
 *
 * For modern browsers
 * 1. The space content is one way to avoid an Opera bug when the
 *    `contenteditable` attribute is included anywhere else in the document.
 *    Otherwise it causes space to appear at the top and bottom of elements
 *    that receive the `clearfix` class.
 * 2. The use of `table` rather than `block` is only necessary if using
 *    `:before` to contain the top-margins of child elements.
 */

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

/*
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */

.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rstaib/jquery-steps/master/demo/css/main.css